# rabbitmq using ldap for authentication and internal for authorization in 2 node cluster not working

Tags: ldap, rabbitmq

Morning,

I clustered two servers and it was working with rabbitmq.config that used just the ldap backend.  I tried to change it so it would use ldap just for authentication and internal for authorization, and I can log into the management console on the first server (rabbitmq01p).  However, if I try to access the 2nd server (rabbitmq02p) management console, it now throws:

Got response code 500 with body

This happens even with a test internal user radmin that I created.
I am not sure what needs to change.

The rabbitmq.config:

```
[
  {rabbit, [
    {loopback_users, []},
    {auth_backends, [{rabbit_auth_backend_ldap, 
rabbit_auth_backend_internal}, rabbit_auth_backend_internal]},
    {log_levels, [{channel, info}, {connection, info}, {federation, info}, 
    mirroring, info}]},
    {tcp_listen_options,
         [binary,
         {packet,        raw},
         {reuseaddr,     true},
         {backlog,       128},
         {nodelay,       true},
         {exit_on_close, false}]
    },
    {default_user, <<"radmin">>},
    {default_pass, <<"radmin">>}

  ]},
  {kernel, [

  ]}
,
  {rabbitmq_management, [
    {listener, [
      {port, 15672}
    ]}
  ]}
   %% {listener, [{port,     12345},
   %%             {ip,       "127.0.0.1"},
   %%             {ssl,      true},
   %%             {ssl_opts, [{cacertfile, "/path/to/cacert.pem"},
   %%                         {certfile,   "/path/to/cert.pem"},
   %%                         {keyfile,    "/path/to/key.pem"}]}]},
,
{rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap, [
    {other_bind, {"CN=LDAP Demo,OU=Generic and Shared 
Accounts,OU=Admin,dc=usa,dc=company,dc=com", "password"}},
    {servers, ["ldap-server.company.com"]},
    {user_dn_lookup_attribute, "sAMAccountName"},
    {dn_lookup_base, "ou=User Accounts,ou=USA,DC=company,DC=com" },
    {user_dn_pattern, "${username}@usa.company.com" },
    {use_ssl, false},
    {port, 3268},
    {log,true},
    {group_lookup_base, "ou=Groups,dc=usa,dc=company,dc=com"},
    {tag_queries, [{administrator, {in_group, "CN=Server 
Team,OU=Groups,DC=usa,DC=company,DC=com"}},
                   {management,    {constant, true}}]}
   ]
  }
].
```

The error in the log:

=ERROR REPORT==== 13-Nov-2017::09:03:26 ===
Ranch listener rabbit_web_dispatch_sup_15672 had connection process started with cowboy_protocol:start_link/4 at <0.1234.0> exit with reason: {[{reason,{badmatch,undefined}},{mfa,{rabbit_mgmt_wm_whoami,is_authorized,2}},{stacktrace,[{rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,env,1,[{file,"src/rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},{line,580}]},{rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,log,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},{line,721}]},{rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,user_login_authentication,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},{line,74}]},{rabbit_access_control,try_authenticate,3,[{file,"src/rabbit_access_control.erl"},{line,88}]},{rabbit_access_control,'-check_user_login/2-fun-0-',4,[{file,"src/rabbit_access_control.erl"},{line,65}]},{lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1248}]},{rabbit_mgmt_util,is_authorized,6,[{file,"src/rabbit_mgmt_util.erl"},{line,160}]},{cowboy_rest,call,3,[{file,"src/cowboy_rest.erl"},{line,976}]}]},{req,[{socket,#Port<0.25192>},{transport,ranch_tcp},{connection,keepalive},{pid,<0.1234.0>},{method,<<"GET">>},{version,'HTTP/1.1'},{peer,{{10,2,2,144},52823}},{host,<<"esrabbitmq02p.usa.company.com">>},{host_info,undefined},{port,15672},{path,<<"/api/whoami">>},{path_info,undefined},{qs,<<>>},{qs_vals,[]},{bindings,[]},{headers,[{<<"host">>,<<"esrabbitmq02p.usa.company.com:15672">>},{<<"connection">>,<<"keep-alive">>},{<<"user-agent">>,<<"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36">>},{<<"authorization">>,<<"Basic cmFkbWpzOnJhZG1pbg==">>},{<<"content-type">>,<<"application/json">>},{<<"accept">>,<<"*/*">>},{<<"referer">>,<<"http://esrabbitmq02p.usa.company.com:15672/">>},{<<"accept-encoding">>,<<"gzip, deflate">>},{<<"accept-language">>,<<"en-US,en;q=0.8">>},{<<"cookie">>,<<"_SI_VID_1.681cceba2200012815576dcc=3bafef640f2a946d6f48e512; _vwo_uuid_v2=5707BE963C1A8F85D47ABE721862DCD2|e694e7c388bfb2dd860621dc71c082fc; _ceg.s=ow9umn; _ceg.u=ow9umn; RDTC=1; __utmz=234506268.1505479911.21.2.utmcsr=favorites.usa.company.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; _SI_VID_3.681cceba2200012815576dcc=3bafef640f2a946d6f48e512; LPVID=lmMWNkODgyOWJiMDYzN2Jk; rxVisitor=15053163485147G3CS2HA9NUHJFVP185Q0ASL8J4DDIV2; amlbcookie=03; iPlanetDirectoryPro=AQIC5wM2LY4Sfcyx28ueXpdDc1glrOUlOpBpriQ5JrEN_3Y.*AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLABMtNjg0NTczODcxNTgzMTczMjU1AAJTMQACMDM.*; __utma=234506268.404039322.1499344780.1509745463.1510321495.40; __utmc=234506268; _ga=GA1.2.404039322.1499344780; m=2258:cmFkbWluOnJhZG1pbg%253D%253D">>}]},{p_headers,[{<<"connection">>,[<<"keep-alive">>]}]},{cookies,undefined},{meta,[]},{body_state,waiting},{buffer,<<>>},{multipart,undefined},{resp_compress,true},{resp_state,waiting},{resp_headers,[{<<"vary">>,<<"origin">>}]},{resp_body,<<>>},{onresponse,#Fun}]},{state,{context,undefined,none,undefined}}],[{cowboy_rest,is_authorized,2,[{file,"src/cowboy_rest.erl"},{line,150}]},{cowboy_protocol,execute,4,[{file,"src/cowboy_protocol.erl"},{line,442}]}]}

Comment: Note that if I change it to use just internal backend and not ldap one on the 2nd server, I can log in to management console at least with the internal user, so it is something about authorization and ldap.  I am not sure why it is working with same rabbitmq.config on the 1st server.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure when/how I missed it, but I had to run (rerun?)

rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap

After this, the authentication worked.